# Unity shadows blink in full-screen only

Tags: unity-game-engine, shadows

So I have a project in unity that has hard shadows only. On my computer, everything works just fine, but when I export it to another computer (which is actually a higher end gaming computer), the shadows blink.

This error only seems to appear on their computer after it has exceeds 1600 x 900.

I have tried all of the solutions in
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/23919/terrain-flickering-due-to-real-time-shadows.html
but none of these work. I have also tried baking light map, but this didn't work either.

Is there a setting I can change to make this blinking stop, or even some code I can write? None of my attempts have worked so far.

---

We tried turning all of the shadows but one off, and the shadows still blink.

This shouldn't be a hardware issue either, since the laptop is using a *Nvidia GeForce GTX 675M*, which is supposed to support shadows in Unity.

---

A Current temporary Solution I am implementing looks like this:

```
void Update ()
    {
        if (Screen.width > 1600 || Screen.height > 900)
        {
            Camera.main.renderingPath = RenderingPath.VertexLit;
        }


    }
```

this removes shadows after that size, but I would like to be able to use shadows anyway, so if you can find the problem, please post it.

Comment: windows? First thing I would try is update (or downgrade!) the graphics drivers. Then consider how much frame buffer memory is needed and how much the graphics card has. Maybe you are simply taxing the hardware too much. Or it is overclocked too much. Either way this isn't a programming question.

Comment: did you see this? http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/shadows-shaking.83286/   Dreamora's answer.

Comment: @Roberto Yes, but this didn't help me either. Thanks though